# jQuery issues on testing form elements values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Good day all.

I have a form where users must fill out some fields, and this form is created dinamically y a php script.

I've done a script that do a test on input fields to check if the users has filled everything.
It is basically a cascade test in where if an error variable is true, the form isn't submitted.

I have done some modifications and I have added a new hidden field to the form, filled by jquery when user clicks a image.

```
$( '.selectLogo' ).bind("click",function(e){
    $( "#operator" ).val( $(this).data("opvalue") );
});
```

then, on the submit event, there is the whole test...

```
if ( !$( "#operator" ).val().length ){
  $(".operatorError").show();
  error=true;
} else{
  $(".operatorError").hide();
}

if(error){
  return false;
}
```

this is the last test I've added on the function, just before testing the error variable and decide if return `true` or `false`.

the problem is that:

IF i'm debugging the script, i.e. I put a breakpoint just over the `if(error)`, everything is fine.
IF i filled the whole form, i.e. the checkForm function just go throught every test and arrive on the decision of returning true or false, everything is ok.

BUT if i filled the form partially, and I try to make a submit without selecting the operator (the new field i've added), the checkForm function stops me, display the error, but at this point, I must click on the operator logo to make the hiden field fills, then I have to click SEVERAL (read 2,3 or sometimes 4) times the submit button to have the form submitted.

It sounds like that the `error` variable retain the value, and the jQuery cache it... or something, does anyone has experienced a similar problem? it is possible to "force" jQuery to "really" test a variable...? Am I complitely wrong and maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: I am guessing, since you are not showing everything: Maybe you have more than one elements with the class `operatorError`. Maybe one as a child of every `#operator` element? If so, you will have to work only on the child `operatorError` element. E.g. use `$(this).children(".operatorError")` in the submit event handler.

Comment: Oh, and it could be that you are creating a global variable with `error=true` if it is not defined before in your function with `var error=false`. In the `else` case you are not modifying it, so it will be set by another event handler call. Set the variable in every case and define the variable as a local variable with `var error=false;` before the if.